Nvidia X Server Display Configuration Prime Display
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 with dual monitor. In the Nvidia X Server Display Configuration menu, I'm seeing a "Prime Display" as third monitor and I cannot disable or delete it. Also, when I drag my mouse to most right, pointer is not stopping on the right edge and it's acting like I have a third monitor. Could you please tell me how can I get rid of it? Screenshot attached.Prime Display
Thank you in advance.
